# Servidor Amazon EC2 Linux sem postfix enviando email localhost

Tags: email, smtp, amazon-aws

Configurei uma instancia Linux no Amazon EC2, instalei o básico para rodar uma aplicação PHP (Apache + PHP + MySQL).

O que me surpreendeu foi quando fiz um teste utilizando a função **mail()** do PHP, recebi no meu email normalmente como se tivesse um servidor SMTP localhost configurado com o seguinte endereço:

```
<apache@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.sa-east-1.compute.internal>
```

**Dúvida:**

Como minha instancia no Amazon EC2 sem ter um servidor SMTP configurado, como postfix ou similar foi capaz de enviar email utilizando a função **mail()** do PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Uma instância possui por default um servidor de email simples, que entrega sua mensagem mas que, na prática, não entrega com a qualidade necessária para o uso em produção. Se é apenas um teste ou um alerta em nível operacional, OK, mas para entrega de mensagens transacionais não é garantida a entrega.

Configure seu servidor para realizar um Pool, passando de fato a fazer um Relay para um servidor com entrega de melhor qualidade, como por exemplo o serviço de entrega de mensagem da própria AWS